# How should I structure my SQLite Database for the fastest query times

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

- My database is never updated, its just read.
- I alway search using the item hash, i.e. i want to get a set of items `WHERE itemHash = 34 OR itemHash = 1345`
- I always need to fetch **all** of the variables (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`).  There is never a case where I just need `var1` for example.

My fetches are currently slow due to the quantity of data and I want to speed them up.

I have two candidate structures.  I wanted to know which is quicker for fetches (if any) and why.

**'Split Form'**

[image: split form]

**'Combined form'**

[image: combined form]

Also is there anything else I can do to speed things up?

I am currently leaning towards the combined form because it means the searches wont have to traverse two queries.  However in the combined form there will be more rows to search though.

Comment: Yea im ticked the little indexed box, i'm not entire sure of the implications of this but im told this helps.

Comment: If your searches are slow "due to the quantity of data" perhaps you should look at the overall picture rather than attempting to optimize individual fetches.  Are the (presumably multiple) fetches all for the same key (hash value)?  What does your overall reference pattern look like?

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks for the reply.  The queries are run for up-to 9 different keys using a compound OR statement.  I am currently running one query at a time.  Will it be better to split into many quires and have only 1 key in each query? What do you mean by overall reference pattern? Should I expand my question to show exactly what I am searching for?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful.  A "real" query statement, plus info on how many rows are typically returned, eg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the item hash a string or number?  That is important as string searches are slower.

As for the base question, because relationships and joining tables together are slower your "combined" model is going to be faster.

However this does raise the question: Have you run instruments and profiled the fetch?  What method call is taking up the most time?  Is it the actual fetch that is slow?